# how to show the rate dialog for my application in android

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I'm developing application that make the user to rate my application in Google play store,
So I want the user when click the rate button in my application, he redirect to the rate dialog in the market not my application page.
My code is :

```
try {
    final String pkgName = getPackageName();
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + pkgName)));
} catch (Exception e) {
    vShowDialog(getString(R.string.cannot_connect_title), getString(R.string.cannot_connect_title) + getString(R.string.error_TryAgain));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do much more then simply open the Google Play app on your desired page. Whatever happens after that is out of your reach.