# How to ask user to rate my app from code?

Tags: android, google-play

I know how to invoke Google Play from my application from the code. However, it starts the main page on Google Play from my application. From that the user may want to go to add rating, but is there a more direct way?

Like, can I have in my app a button 'Hated it' which will result in 1 star being posted on Google Play for my app and a button 'Loved it' which will result in 5 stars?

Comment: This should get you a more direct link: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/14091259/how-to-show-the-rate-dialog-for-my-application-in-android   ...I don't think the second is possible... Never seen it in app.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I already know. Ok then..

Comment: Application rating has to be done by the user, inside the Google Play Store. So the option that @anthropomo has suggested is pretty much the only way.

Comment: I read the above as saying the main page of Play, not the page of your app. Ambiguity on the internet!

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeRoy That's the answer then.. If you post the same as the answer I will gladly accept.

Comment: If you think about it, if your app could have a "Loved It" button that resulted in 5 stars, your app could also give itself a 5-star rating if the user clicked "Hated It", or just every time it launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android applications have to be rated by the user inside the Google Play Store. The best you can do is to redirect the user to your application's Google Play page.

Therefore, it's not possible for you to implement a simple way for the user to grant you a 1 to 5 star rating directly inside your application.

Answer (score 3):

What I did in my App was to show the user a dialog after the app was started a few times, say 15 times or something like that (If your users use the app a lot, it would be more probably that they rate it good, because they are using the app, so do not ask them in the first days of use). What the dialog shows is a text where you ask the user to rate the app, ignore, etc. If they press "rate" and they are linked to the google play they may rate the app, because they already decided to rate it pressing the button from your dialog. I do not know there is a "direct" method to do this like you are thinking. Try my method instead.

See my example [Code Example](http://pastebin.com/79YRKYD2)

Comment: Great idea about those 15 times! Thanks!

Comment: A step further, tell them how many times they have used the app, maybe?